# How to get the sum of change of one column while a condition on another column is true?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to evaluate the change of one Pandas column that occurs while another column fulfills a certain condition.

Assuming a DataFrame `df` with a DateTimeIndex and two columns:

```
timestamp   operating_time  sensor_values
2022-03-23 23:57:59.802000+00:00    8.172000e+06    398.15
2022-03-23 23:57:59.818000+00:00    8.172000e+06    397.85
2022-03-23 23:58:59.805000+00:00    8.172000e+06    397.5
2022-03-23 23:58:59.821000+00:00    8.172000e+06    NaN
2022-03-23 23:59:59.793000+00:00    8.172000e+06    397.15
...
```

Now I would like to know how much operating_time passed while `sensor_values < 398` and how much operating_time passed while `sensor_values >= 398`.

I tried to divide the data into to DataFrames like this:

```
df_low = df[df['sensor_values'] < 398]
df_high = df[df['sensor_values'] >= 398]
```

However if I then calculate by how much the `operating_time` changes for each DataFrame with

```
df_low['operating_time'].diff().sum()
df_high['operating_time'].diff().sum()
```

I get basically the same value as it seems Pandas is filling the NaN gaps for diff().

How can I find out how much operating time `sensor_values` was above and below a certain value?

Plot of `sensor_values` in blue and `operating_time` in red:
[image: sensor_values in blue and operating_time in red]

The expected output would be two numbers representing the operating time that was spend over the threshold and below the threshold. So in the example image the operating time increases from roughly 1e6 minutes to roughly 8e6 minutes. The two numbers should therefore add up to 7e6 minutes.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: Hi @richardec thanks for your comment! I added the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use:

```
out = (df['operating_time']
       .diff()
       .groupby(np.where(df['sensor_values'].gt(398), '>398', '≤398'))
       .sum()
      )
```

output (here with limited example):

```
>398    0.0
≤398    0.0
Name: operating_time, dtype: float64
```

or, directly from the timestamps:

```
out = (pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
       .diff()
       .groupby(np.where(df['sensor_values'].gt(398), '>398', '≤398'))
       .sum()
      )
```

output:

```
>398          0 days 00:00:00
≤398   0 days 00:01:59.991000
Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, thanks for your answer! This seems to get really close to what I'm looking for. However if I add up both values I get ~2.4e6 instead of ~7e6. Do you have an idea where the missing time is lost?

Comment: I was able to solve that issue by using `df.interpolate()` before using your method to fill the gaps. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Axel glad it worked for you!